# Radon or cosmic ray?

Tags: experimental-physics, home-experiment, radioactivity, particle-detectors, cosmic-rays

My student constructed a cloud chamber to detect the background radiation. It is very simple and efficient.

But the question is, is the radiation mostly from the Radon gas or the cosmic ray?

See some video here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xky3f1aSkB8

Comment: Like the video says, the big fat track are radon-produced alpha particles. They look different.

Comment: Related: [Random directions of the trajectories in a cloud chamber](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/315343/random-directions-of-the-trajectories-in-a-cloud-chamber/315377#315377)

Comment: remember there are about one cosmic ray muon passing per cm^2 per minute, http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/muonatm.html at sea level,  so a 60 cm^2 area will have one muon per second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless your student is purposely placing a radioactive source into the chamber, or there are sources near the chamber, the more likely suspect is a cosmic ray if you are seeing condensation trails.

To see radon induced trails from the environment would likely mean you have dangerous levels in your environment. Without an intentional source placed, and unless you are observing in a uranium mine or in a building with known radon outgassing from the floors, the more likely source of the trails you are seeing is from cosmic rays.